# how to create Django preferences (Site dashboard)

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

Hi I have **ready Django project** and I want to create a **control panel** for it, for example I want to add a field with the name of the site, a field with a description of the site, and a field with the logo of the site, and I call them in the templates instead of changing them manually through the editor every time.

I upload the website logo to the static file and want to add an option to change it from the control panel instead of manually replacing it from the server.

I have attached an illustration of what I want to reach.

Thank you

[image: Illustrative picture]

Comment: could it be an option to create a 'Site' model class with the attributes you've mentioned? It appears you could use a FileField model field for processing an uploaded logo file, and these 'Site' object fields could be edited in the prebuilt Django Admin site

Comment: The problem is that Django models are dynamically repeatable

Therefore, it is not possible to create a single static page with a value that is stored in the database one time

Answer (score 0):

I searched and did not find a solution for this, but I want to share the solution that I adopted myself
I created a new application called Settings and through it I created a modle for each setting I wanted.

**UPDATED**

I create new model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class Option(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=_('Key'), null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=_('Value'), null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key
```

Thus, you can use the values stored in the database:

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_option(key, default):
    op = Option.objects.filter(key=key).first()
    if op and op.value != '':
        option = op.value
    else:
        option = default
    return option
```